# How to import debug into a TypeScript project you'll use rollup on?

Tags: angular, typescript, rollupjs, npm-debug

I've got an Angular 2 project and have been using [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) with no problems.  I'm now trying to use [rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) and I get the error:

```
Cannot call a namespace ('debugModule')
```

This refers to the way I import debug:

```
import * as debugModule from 'debug';
```

I've seen that the solution to this is to import without using the `* as someName` syntax, like this:

```
import debug from 'debug';
```

or maybe:

```
import { Debug } from 'debug';
```

...but neither of those work (`has no default export` and `has no exported member 'Debug'`).  I've done my best to look at the source of both `debug` and `@types/debug` 
to see what I should import, but all I can see is from `@types/debug` - there are `IDebug` and `IDebugger` interfaces which aren't what I'm looking for.

How should I be importing `debug` such that `rollup` will be OK with it?

It looks like I can coerce it into working by calling it this way:

```
debug = debugModule.call(this, 'module:component');
```

Although I'm not sure what repercussions that might have going forward...

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know why, but if you have installed `@types/debug` then `import debug from 'debug'` won't work, but if you just remove `@types/debug` then you can import it.  This doesn't solve all the problems I have with `debug` when using rollup, but it stops the `Cannot call namespace` problem and you can call `debug` normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can import it as follows

```
import * as debugModule from 'debug';
const debug = debugModule()
```